# jndi-name property override - JUnit - Spring - Struts Integration test

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, websphere, jndi

I am trying to write integration test that uses JUnit, Struts2, Spring, JPA/Hibernate.

The application is working fine in WebSphere. The Integration tests are run outside of WebSphere.

struts2-junit-plugin and spring-struts plugin both are used. My test class extends `StrutsSpringTestCase`.

This is the sample code in the test method:

```
ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("custSearch");
assertNotNull(proxy);
```

It loads struts.xml, applicationContext.xml and jpaContext.xml.

In the jpaContext.xml I have the following entry.

```
<bean id="dsSQLServer" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" p:jndi-name="${sql.jndi.name}"/>
```

`sql.jndi.name` comes from the properties file and is setup in WebSphere.

I went TO properties file and replaced the local jndi url with full jndi url that I got from executing dumpNamespaces.bat of Websphere. which is something like

```
MycomnameNode01Cell/nodes/C1A-mYNode/servers/mYSrv/jdbc/sql_src
```

However, when I run the JUnit test case from eclipse I get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceSQLServer' defined in URL [file:/C:/workspace/context/jpaContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:148)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsSpringTestCase.setupBeforeInitDispatcher(StrutsSpringTestCase.java:38)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.setUp(StrutsTestCase.java:187)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:245)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.initializeDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:318)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:348)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:428)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 25 more
```

Questions:

1. Should the JNDI URL be different? Is it possible to specify the FULL URL like iiop:localhost:/?
2. Is it possible to override jndi-name setting in `@BeforeClass` method or with Static initializer? Because, the JNDI URL above, Provider URL is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JNDI context is usually provided by your app server (Websphere). As you're running your test from the outside of Websphere, you won't be able to access to a local JNDI. I see 3 solutions...

1. Ensure that you're connected to the remote JNDI

   You should initialize your access properties in a @BeforeClass method :

   ```
   Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
   env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://server:2809");
   env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
   Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
   ```

   This way you'll be able to access to the remote JNDI, but a datasource is not supposed to be serialized. It cannot be transfered remotely.
2. Setup a local JNDI

   Spring is providing a [SimpleNamingContextBuilder class](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) that can be used in the @BeforeClass method to setup a local JNDI and fill it with a hand made datasource
3. Don't load the jpaContext.xml file

   Make an other one which will provide the dsSQLServer bean, but without accessing the JNDI. A [SimpleDriverDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SimpleDriverDataSource.html) would probably be perfect.

My preferred solution is #3.

Comment: I like your approaches. Let me try the last one.